# ID3 Album Art / Cover Tag Field

Tags: id3, id3-tag, id3v2, artwork

What is the field name for covers / album arts in id3 tags?

For eg. :

Title : title - TT2 - TIT2

Artist :  artist - TP1 - TPE1

Album : album - TAL - TALB

Cover: ? - ? - ?

I hope somebody can help me...

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 5):

The 'field' (id3 tag frame) name is APIC.

```
<Header for 'Attached picture', ID: "APIC">
Text encoding   $xx
MIME type       <text string> $00
Picture type    $xx
Description     <text string according to encoding> $00 (00)
Picture data    <binary data>
```

You can find more details here: http://id3.org/id3v2.3.0

Have a look at 4.15 Attached Picture