# Extract image from mp3 files inside browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, web, audio, mp3, web-audio-api

Is there any cross browser way to get embedded image(cover image) from mp3 or other audio files inside the browser using javascript?

All the tutorials talk about html audio tag. But not the image.
Does anyone knows?
Or should it be done inside the server (extracting image from mp3 + other audio formats).

Environment :-
Python, django, JavaScript, web browsers.

Comment: Can mp3 files even contain images?  They are an audio container, not an image container.   Try jpg or png maybe.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I think the OP may be referring to the [ID3 tag for album artwork: APIC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18292648/id3-album-art-cover-tag-field)

Comment: Just download some mp3 from internet. Now embed them in web page with html audio tag. You can only see audio file. But if you play it using desktop(windows) player, You can see cover image. Or in windows file explorer you can see this image as file(mp3) icon.

Comment: I think `id3js` lib do exactly what you need. Please check an example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-bgxzfp?file=src%2FApp.tsx

Comment: This is what I use:  https://github.com/Borewit/music-metadata-browser  It's awesome... supports a ton of formats.

Comment: Both id3js and music-metadata-browser are good. Thank you both of you. @Brad . .